# How do I print the max and min in a data set as well as the correllating dates in Python 3?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, max, min

I am working with a large weather data set and I am trying to find the maximum and minimum values for five different parameters. They are precipitation, snow fall, average temperature, max temperature, and minimum temperature. My goal is to be able to find the highest and lowest values for each of these and print out the number and the date in which it occurred, however I have a noisy data set and many blank or zero values. I have managed to make the blank values into None types, but I do not want to include them in any of my calculations.

Currently I am stuck trying to get multiple outputs for the maximum value:

```
def High(value):
                if value == row['PRCP']:
                    maxPrec = max(row['PRCP'] for row in reader)
                    print(row['DATE'])
                    return maxPrec
                elif value == row['SNOW']:
                    maxSnow = max(row['SNOW'] for row in reader)
                    print(row['DATE'])
                    return maxSnow
                elif value == row['TAVG']:
                    maxTavg = max(row['TAVG'] for row in reader)
                    return maxTavg
                elif value == row['TMIN']:
                    maxTmin = max(row['TMIN'] for row in reader)
                    print(row['DATE'])
                    return maxTmin
                elif value == row['TMAX']:
                    maxTmax = max(row['TMAX'] for row in reader)
                    return maxTmax

    print(High(row['PRCP']))
```

If I use my function a second time for a different variable I get an invalid type. I am also not sure how to print the correlating date, if you are able to help me with either of these problems it would be much appreciated.

A sample the file output is below:

```
"STATION","NAME","DATE","PRCP","SNOW","SNWD","TAVG","TMAX","TMIN"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-01",,,,"46","56","35"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-02",,,,"52","59","45"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-03","0.01",,,"58","66","50"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-04","0.00",,,"62","71","53"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-05","0.00",,,"63","75","51"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-06","0.00",,,"73","82","63"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-07","0.00",,,"78","85","70"
"USW00003894","CLARKSVILLE OUTLAW AIRPORT, TN US","2001-04-08","0.00",,,"75","83","67"
```

I have had a hard time finding any good material to help me with large data set parsing, so if you have any suggestions on sites that may lead me in the right direction those would be helpful too.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to try pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pandas DataFrame from your csv to make the data much easier to work with.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_filename')
max_precip_index = data['PRCP'].idxmax()  # Get index of max value
min_precip_index = data['PRCP'].idxmin()  # Get index of min value
print (data.iloc[max_precip_index][['PRCP', 'DATE']])  # Print prcp and date value at the row corresponding to the found index.
```